Is it possible to ping a local port on rust?
I have a program that sets up a minecraft server on port 25565 and the only way I can think of to monitor the status is to ping the port it is hosted on but I cant find anything about pinging a specific port. Is this possible or is there a better way to do it?
let addr = "8.8.8.8".parse().unwrap();
    let data = [1,2,3,4];  // ping data
    let data_arc = Arc::new(&data[..]);
    let timeout = Duration::from_secs(1);
    let options = ping_rs::PingOptions { ttl: 128, dont_fragment: true };
    let future = ping_rs::send_ping_async(&addr, timeout, data_arc, Some(&options));
    let result = futures::executor::block_on(future);
    match result {
        Ok(reply) => println!("Reply from {}: bytes={} time={}ms TTL={}", reply.address, data.len(), reply.rtt, options.ttl),
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e)
    }

The documentation mentions nothing about pinging a port.

Classical ping is using ICMP which has no concept of ports. What you really need to do instead is to simply check if you can connect to the socket (TCP sockets - which is probably what you have) or if you can send data to the port and get a reply back (UDP).

Minecraft supports the SLP, Query and RCON protocols which can be used to monitor the server status.

Note the that the answers on serverfault boil down to: simply open a connection to the host:port combination, i.e. TcpStream::connect (addr).is_ok() will tell you if the port is open and reachable.
